# Web server tolerance to high client poll rate: Cowboy vs. Yaws web servers

Tags: http, erlang, mnesia, yaws, cowboy

I have been building a real-time notification system. It’s part of a web application, but events have to be seen as soon as they occur. Long polling was not an option because it would be expensive for the web server to hold on to connections when no events are available, so I had to go for short-lived polls.

Each client hits the web server every, say, 2 seconds (this is a fairly high rate). When events are available, they are sent as JSON to the JavaScript client. Now, this requires a server set-up to handle a high number of short-lived connections. I have implemented one such system using the Yaws web server. However, because Yaws starts quite a number of many other services, it feels heavy and connections begin to get either refused or aborted when they go beyond 30,000 (maybe because I am running some ETS Tables in the same Erlang VM as Yaws is running on [separating these may require `rpc:call/4`, which—I fear—will increase latency]). I know that there are operating-system-specific tweaks to do, and those have been done.

This would not be a problem if it was easy to cluster up several Yaws instances. In Yaws, i am using a few appmods, and I am doing things RESTfully. I was thinking that the Cowboy web server might enhance things a bit here. I have not used Cowboy before, but I have used Misultin. Looking at Cowboy, it is a full fledged OTP Application and it seems to be easy to cluster, and being lightweight, may perhaps increase on the number of clients the overall system can handle. Storage is on Mnesia, which I can distribute easily to add more nodes (maybe by replication), so that there is a Cowboy instance in front of every Mnesia instance.

My questions are:

1. Is my speculation correct, that if I switched from Yaws to Cowboy, I might increase the performance significantly?
2. Yaws has a clean API via `Appmods` and the `#arg{}` record. Does Cowboy have an equivalent of these two things (illustrate please)?
3. Can `Cowboy` handle file uploads? If so, which server (Yaws or Cowboy), in your opinion would be better to use in the case of frequent file uploads? Illustrate how file uploads are done with Cowboy.
4. It is possible to run several Yaws instances on the same machine. Do you think that creating many Yaws instances per server (physical box) and having the client-load distributed across these would help? What do I need to know about doing this?
5. When I set the `yaws.conf` parameter `max_connections = nolimit`, how would I specify the same in Cowboy?

Now, I followed the [interview with Cowboy author](http://pdincau.wordpress.com/2012/06/27/an-interview-with-erlang-cowboy-loic-hoguin-lhoguin/) and he discusses the reasons why Cowboy is more lightweight than Yaws. He says that

> The biggest difference is the use of binaries instead of lists. The generic acceptor pool is another. I could list a lot of other small differences but I figure these aren’t the most interesting.

That because Cowboy uses the listener-pool library [Ranch](https://github.com/extend/ranch), it somehow ends up with a higher capability of handling more connections, plus the use of binaries and not lists.

Another quote from the same interview:

> Since we use one process per connection instead of two, and we use binaries instead of lists, we end up using a lot less memory than other projects without user intervention. Cowboy is also lazy, it doesn’t do anything unless required. So we don’t have much in memory until the user starts calling functions.

I wonder how yaws handles this case. Somehow, my problem domain needs lightweight HTTP handling. It’s actually true that Yaws will lead to more memory consumption as compared to say, Mochiweb, Misultin or Cowboy. My greatest concern is that Yaws has the best/cleanest API whereby it gives us access to the `#arg{}` containing everything we need as an Erlang record, so that we can get them out ourselves, than the others which have numerous functions for extracting stuff outside. Even the documentation: Yaws docs are pretty good and straightforward. Perhaps I need to look at more Cowboy code for things like file uploading and simple `GET` and `POST` request handling.

Otherwise, the questions I asked earlier, remain as pressing concerns. Yaws is pretty good, but seems to be overkill for this fast light-weight short-lived high rate poll situation, what do you think?

Comment: A down vote ought to come with a `reason`. Every question that calls for other opinions is down voted. I wonder what would be the reason. Someone explain why this question is down voted. If you have no answer, why not `beat it` off this page ? hah ?

Comment: I don't understand this part of what you wrote: "...yaws starts quite a number of many other services..." From what I can see, Yaws registers 8 processes, including its supervisors, logger, etc. This to me does not qualify as "quite a number of many other services."

Comment: Can you explain what trouble you're having clustering yaws instances?

Comment: i have done some edits. Thank you @Vinoski

Comment: You might consider trying the new Yaws custom dispatch feature. You supply a dispatcher module with a dispatch/1 function. It gets an `#arg{}` record like an appmod but you handle writing the response to the socket yourself. See [this commit](https://github.com/klacke/yaws/commit/75dbb60c734536bdcc6482bd5ab11340ab0d47fc) for more details. Alternatively, consider dropping a test case on the [Yaws mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/erlyaws-list) so we can take a look at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your 30000 refusal limit sounds an awful lot like a 32k limit somewhere. Either the default process count, which is 32k, or some system limit on file descriptors and so on. You should not rule out the possibility that the limitation is on the kernel side of things. I've seen systems come to their limits quite easily due to kernel configurations which can be really hard to handle.